# Is it possible to use a newer version of the aws-sdk than provided in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

The latest version of the aws-sdk has functions for ComprehendMedical, which I'd like to create a lambda function for.

However, the version of the AWS-SDK is a few months outdated, and not able to use these functions yet. Wondering if there is a way to use the latest library?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend you create a Library bundle and create a **[Lambda Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)** with it with the desired version of AWS-SDK in the Library bundle (including any other libraries that you want). Once you have the Lambda layer set you can assign it to your Lambda function(s). This helps with a reduced code size of your Lambda function without having the need to bundle up all the libraries you need with every single Lambda Function. Considering AWS-SDK to be a pretty large library, Lambda Layer will help you manage the size of your individual Lambda functions with purely your code in it.

The steps are simple.

1. Create a directory named `nodejs`, this is going to be your project directory. The name [must](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path) be `nodejs`.
2. Perform
   `npm init` inside of this directory.
3. Install all the libraries from
   npm using `npm install --save`. **Note:** local install is important.
4. Once done, zip up the `nodejs` directory and upload it to a Lambda
   Layer.
5. Use the Lambda Layer in all your Lambda functions.

Check out my [article](https://medium.com/@anjanava.biswas/nodejs-runtime-environment-with-aws-lambda-layers-f3914613e20e) for the full details on how to set up a Lambda Layer for Node JS dependencies. I reckon that going forward, Lambda Layer should be everyone's choice of dependency management in Lambda.

**NOTE**: Lambda Layer was introduced <s>recently</s> in AWS re:Invent 2018. It is not only compatible with NodeJS, but also with pretty much any other Language (as per Amazon) like Python, Java, C#, C++ (yes!), Go, Rust etc.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you simply need to bundle the latest version of the SDK in your Lambda function's deployment file, instead of relying on the version that is there.

Answer (score 1):

On Default Lambda uses these SDKs
AWS SDK for JavaScript – 2.290.0
SDK for Python (Boto3) – 3-1.7.74 botocore-1.10.74

But you can install the newest SDK via npm (or whatever you are using) and then upload the whole bunch of files to lamda.

Take a look at SLS (serverless Framework) it is easy to add files you want to deploy ;)

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy way. 
If you have a webpack.config.js you could just change `externals: ['aws-sdk'],` to `externals: [],`.

This way it will force to take the node package you sending in. Sure it will take some extra time to upload and so on, put an easy quick fix you can try.